# How can I make sure that my Arduino stopwatch's timing is exact?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a school assignment to create a stopwatch using Multifunction Shield. The functionality is simple: the leftmost button is for start/stop and the rightmost button is for resetting, if the stopwatch is stopped. The precision is 100ms.

My code is working as expected I thought, but my teacher returned it saying that I cannot guarantee that the code is executed every 100ms so that the stopwatch does not lag behind. What am I doing wrong?

There's a bit of a legacy code from previous HW, hope it's not a problem.

```
// Funshield Constants

// Constants for switching ON/OFF
constexpr int ON = LOW;
constexpr int OFF = HIGH;

// 7-Segs
constexpr int latchPin = 4;
constexpr int clockPin = 7;
constexpr int dataPin = 8;

// Buzzer
constexpr int buzzerPin = 3;

// LEDS
constexpr int firstPin = 13;
constexpr int secondPin = 12;
constexpr int thirdPin = 11;
constexpr int fourthPin = 10;

// Buttons
constexpr int firstButton = A1;
constexpr int secondButton = A2;
constexpr int thirdButton = A3;

// Trimr
constexpr int trimrPin = A0;

// Digits
constexpr int digits[11] = { 0xC0, 0xF9, 0xA4, 0xB0, 0x99, 0x92, 0x82, 0xF8, 0x80, 0x90, 0xFF };
constexpr int digitsPos[4] = { 0x08, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01 };

// End of Funshield Constants

// Beginning of the Program

// Buttons Variables
unsigned int buttons[] = {firstButton, secondButton, thirdButton};
unsigned int lengthOfButtons = sizeof(buttons) / sizeof(buttons[0]);
unsigned int previousButtonState[] = {1, 1, 1};

// Global Variables
unsigned long int previousMillis = millis();
unsigned int numberDigits[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
unsigned int interval = 100;
bool isRunning = false;
int numberLength = 0;
int digitIndex = 0;
int dotIndex = 1;
int number = 0;

int DISPLAY_DECIMAL_DOT = 0x7F;

// Functions
unsigned long int displayController(unsigned long int previousMillis, unsigned int interval) {
  unsigned long int currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) { 
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    updateSetNumber(++number, 1);
  }

  return previousMillis;
}

int calculateNumberLength(int innerNumber) {
  int len = 0;
  while (innerNumber != 0) {
    innerNumber = innerNumber / 10;
    len++;
  }

  if (len <= dotIndex) len = dotIndex + 1;
  return len;
}

void updateSetNumber(int innerNumber, int dot) {
  numberLength = calculateNumberLength(innerNumber) - 1;
  dotIndex = dot;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    numberDigits[i] = innerNumber % 10;
    innerNumber = innerNumber / 10;
  }
}

void displayLoop() {
  if (digitIndex > numberLength) {
    digitIndex = (digitIndex + 1) % 4;
    return;
  }

  if ((digitIndex == dotIndex) && (dotIndex > 0)) {
    displayDigit(digits[numberDigits[digitIndex]] & DISPLAY_DECIMAL_DOT, digitsPos[digitIndex]);    
  } else {
    displayDigit(digits[numberDigits[digitIndex]], digitsPos[digitIndex]);  
  }
  digitIndex = (digitIndex + 1) % 4;
}

void displayDigit(byte digit, byte pos) {
  digitalWrite(latchPin, OFF);
  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, digit);
  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, pos);
  digitalWrite(latchPin, ON);
  digitalWrite(latchPin, OFF);
}

// Program
void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfButtons; i++) {
    pinMode(buttons[i], INPUT);
  }

  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (isRunning) {
    previousMillis = displayController(previousMillis, interval);
  }

  unsigned int currentButtonState = digitalRead(buttons[0]);
  if ((!isRunning) && (digitalRead(buttons[2]) == ON)) {
      digitIndex = 0;
      number = 0;
      updateSetNumber(number, 1);
  }

  displayLoop();

  if (currentButtonState != previousButtonState[0]) {
    if (currentButtonState == ON) {
      isRunning = !isRunning;
    }
    previousButtonState[0] = currentButtonState;
  }
}
```

Comment: previousMillis is global.   Why are you passing it around by copy and returning it?  That is confusing.  Fix things like that and the other logic problems will start to make themselves more obvious.

Comment: Also there are hardware-related reasons why this is can ever be anything but a crude timer, as you''re relying on the internal oscillator.  But that's not a software issue.

Comment: @Delta_G yes, my bad. Thanks for that point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem your teacher is pointing to is probably how you update previousMillis.  Imagine that for some reason, an interrupt took too long or you fall victim to the fact that millis skips a number every now and then and your function doesn't get called until 102ms after the last time.  Since you set previousMillis to currentMillis, you're going to be off by that 2ms from now on.  Instead, add the interval to the previousMillis variable.  That way you cancel out that little lag and the next tick is on time.

```
if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
   previousMillis += interval;  // instead of = currentMillis which may be off
  }
```

Comment: You were right basically. However your code snippet was not. It was not enough to make it work as expected, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah it wasn’t meant to give you the answer just get you in the right direction.  I don’t just do your homework for you.  How would that be helpful?

Comment: What it did was that it froze the 7-seg display, so it appeared as if the timer was stopped, but the timer went on in the background. Afterwards, when I clicked the button to resume the timer it just jumped to whatever the value there was in the background.

Comment: Ok, yeah, I wasn't trying to rewrite your code.  You were supposed to take that change in thinking and figure out how to work it into your particular code.  It wasn't meant to be a drop in copy-and-paste answer.